# Is it possible to save a preview

Tags: visual-studio-code, mermaid

I have installed [mermaid](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vstirbu.vscode-mermaid-preview) to be able to generate sequence diagrams. Is there a general way of saving "Previews" in Vs Code?

Comment: I'm on the VSCode team. There is not a general solution for this as of VSCode 1.8, so this is something that the extension author would have to implement. Are you looking to save the preview as html, a pdf, or something else?

Comment: Thanks. I was just looking for some way of save the diagram for others to see.

Comment: Ok, I recommend letting the extension author known that this is a feature you would like to see implemented. There's already a request tracking this on github: https://github.com/vstirbu/vscode-mermaid-preview/issues/5

Comment: Thanks. Well spotted!

Comment: Will [print screen](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcut-for-print-screen-601210c0-b3a9-7b58-bc40-bae4dcf5f108#:~:text=Depending%20on%20your%20hardware%2C%20you,which%20can%20then%20be%20printed.), [greenshot](https://getgreenshot.org/) or other screen capturing tool work for you?

Comment: Although it may not be relevant to your use case (VS Code), I've found the Chrome extension [GoFullPage - Full Page Screen Capture](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gofullpage-full-page-scre/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl) captures large diagrams nicely (if your in Chrome Browser). You'll have to download and edit/trim its resulting PNG file. Works for me.